# stuck with creating rent table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

i want to create a php with mysql to do the following:

lets say that i have a shop i want to rent, rent will be weekly or monthly. I'm searching for the best way to create this table, so i can do easy queries to calculate free weeks or months.

**EDIT**

let say i have

> ID, START_DATE,RENING_TYPE,CLIENT_ID

where Start_date is the start date for renting, and RENTING_TYPE is weekly or monthly

how should i run a query to know all the empty weeks or month so new clients may reserve that week/month

for example a client reserve July month another client reserve the first week in June, if a new client logged in to my system and want to check all the available weeks/months, how can i achieve that ?

Comment: More info please... What kind of data does this table hold and what kind of queries will you run?

Comment: I added additional info, sorry for that

Comment: +1 For adding additional info upon request. Now it's a question to work with.

Comment: I think you should reword the 3rd paragraph to : `lets say that I have a building I want to rent out, rent will be weekly or monthly. I'm searching for the best way to create this table, so I can calculate available weeks or months.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should return all the free intervals between bookings. It gets all suspected free days (end day + 1) if they have not already been booked, then it searches to find the next booked day. Giving you output like this

```
Start Free | End Free
-----------------------
2011-02-03 | 2011-02-06
2011-02-08 | 2011-02-12
2011-02-20 | 2011-03-02
```

You can then get the exact dates inbetween using PHP.

The query:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(r2.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY), 
(
    SELECT DATE_SUB(MIN(starting_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    FROM renting_table as r1
    WHERE r1.starting_date > r2.end_date
)   
FROM renting_table as r2
WHERE DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) not in
(
    SELECT r3.start_date
    FROM renting_table as r3
)
```

Note: I'm very rusty with SQL so the syntax will probably be off but I think the logic is sound. I hope this gives you a nod in the right direction at least!

Answer (score 1):

I can't advise an holistic approach, but would recommend that you first simplify the assignment. Instead of trying to handle both months and weeks, just concentrate on weeks. You can use a bit of business logic to equate one month to four weeks.

Thus you get rid of RENTING_TYPE for a start. And instead include precalculated and exact dates to work with, and just an occupation runtime in WEEKS:

```
ID, CLIENT_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, WEEKS
```

Maybe DAYS would work out even better to evade granularity issues when a shop is rented weekly or monthly alternating. Not much of an query expert, so I would actually prefer looping through the dates in PHP instead of using a self-join etc.

If that's not fast enough (too many shops), I would even devise a `CLIENT_ID=0` filler to mark free spots. That simplifies the searching tremendously and updates are not much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I assume START_DATE is an absolute day (# from 1.1.1970) and RENTING_TYPE is the duration (via JOIN or just so). So your script will do following(I failed to describe in words sorry)

```
//$reservations = array(start_date => object(id=>1,duration=>7,etc..))
$remainingReservedDays = 0;
for($day = $start;$day < $end;$day++){
    if($remainingReservedDays > 0){
        echo 'reserved day<br />';//or grayed out checkbox or whatever
        $remainingReservedDays--;
    } else if(isset($reservations[$day])){ //new reservation starting today
        echo 'reserved<br />';//TODO: make me DRY
        $remainingReservedDays = $reservations[$day]->duration;
    } else {
        echo 'free atleast for a week';
        //TODO check if available for month
        //lookup next reservation start_date
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> lets say that i have a shop i want to
>   rent, rent will be weekly or monthly.
>   I'm searching for the best way to
>   create this table, so i can do easy
>   queries to calculate free weeks or
>   months.

You know what's going to happen if someone wants to rent your shop for 18 days? You're going to rent it to them for 18 days. A bird in the hand . . .

- Store the ending date.
  Rental contracts are always written
  with specific start dates and end
  dates.
- Drop rental_type from the table. It might be convenient to move it to the user interface. But neither the user interface nor the database should limit you to renting only for a week or a month.
- If CLIENT_ID refers to the owner it
  doesn't belong in this table. You
  can't persuade me that the owner is
  dependent on the rental period.
- If CLIENT_ID refers to the tenant, it
  should *probably* be in another
  table. Although it's possible your
  business requirements dictate that
  you'll only rent to one individual,
  it's not unusual to rent things like
  shops to several tenants at a time.
  All their names go on the rental
  agreement, usually making them
  jointly liable for the rent. (Among
  other things.)
- Index the start date and end date columns.

Now, use SamG's query.